# For every $x$ $\%$ change in variable $y$, there is an implied $z$ $\%$ change in variable $N$ - statistics

Tags: statistics, regression

I had a general maths question. I am trying to find the right topic to study for my problem. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the correct direction to study.

**The general problem is**: For every $x$ $\%$ change in variable $y$, there is an implied $z$ $\%$ change in variable $N$. E.g. for every $2$ $\%$ rise in unemployment, there is an implied $5$ $\%$ fall in the stock market.

**I believe the correct topic to study for this type of problem is**: Linear regression in statistics and $\beta$-Coefficients (in linear regression) to analyze sensitivity. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is empirical then the linear regression is what you need to use in order to answer your question. Normally in linear regression, we have predictors (inputs) $x_i$ and a criterion $y$ (output) [note that we can also have multiple outputs]. The linear regression can be stated as

$$y_n = w_0 + w_1x_{1,n}+...+w_px_{p,n} + \varepsilon_n,$$

in which $n$ designates the $n^{\text{th}}$ observation and $x_{i,n}$ the value of the $i^{\text{th}}$ predictor for the $n^{\text{th}}$ observation. As the linear model will always have some error associated with it we also need to add the error $\varepsilon_n$ of the $n^{\text{th}}$ observation. The parameters $w_j$ for $j=0,...,p$ are the weights (in statistics $\beta_j$).

Your statements can only be made if you have a statistically insignificant $w_0$ then you can interpret the $w_j$ as slopes. E.g. if we consider $w_1 = 0.5=\Delta y / \Delta x_1$. We must assume that all other predictors do not change. Then we can say if we increase $x_1$ by $\Delta x_1$ the output $y$ will increase by $\Delta y = w_1~\Delta x_1 =0.5\Delta x_1$.

If you have a statistically significant $w_0$ then you could redefine your output as $y_n-w_0$. Then you can do the same with this new output.

Comment: Hi machine learner, thank you for your answer it makes sense. I have started using R and Excel Regression to put this together now, thanks!